# How to Add a txt file as memo in the project folder of Android-Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

With Eclipse in the project folder was possible to add several file.txt
which they were very useful for me to write TODO list or other notes.

Now i begins to convert some project form Eclipse to Android Studio but the import procedure it not import such txt files.
I then try to add them manualy but the are not accepted by Android Studio.

[image: my txt file from eclipse project]

thanks

Comment: How did you try to add them, and what do you mean by "not accepted"?

Comment: i drag the file  into the app folder, but after i drop the file there are nowhere

Answer (score 0):

I found my files by selecting the Project tab on the left, then "Project Files" from the popup in the top left corner.